# Saving the weights of VGG-16 model trained in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

How to save the weights of VGG-16 model after training it? How to load the saved weights in to the model?

I tried this:

```
fname = "weights-Test-CNN.hdf5"

custom_vgg_model.save_weights(fname,overwrite=True)
custom_vgg_model.load_weights(weights-Test-CNN.hdf5, by_name=False)
```

---

I got following error:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 custom_vgg_model.load_weights(weights-Test-CNN.hdf5, by_name=False)
>
> NameError: name 'weights' is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save and load weights in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266383/save-and-load-weights-in-keras)

Comment: You just forgot the quotes around weights-Test-CNN.hdf5... `custom_vgg_model.load_weights("weights-Test-CNN.hdf5", by_name=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Surround the second weights-Test-CNN.hdf5 with quotes or you use *fname* as you have defined...

```
custom_vgg_model.load_weights("weights-Test-CNN.hdf5", by_name=False)
```