# How to predict using loaded weights of two identical nets in Siamese Networks?

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-recognition, siamese-network

How can i use saved weights of the two identical nets in a Siamese Network -> similarity net (right/ siamese) and the feature generator (left).

I have followed and implemented [this](https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/image-similarity-with-siamese-networks/output) example for image similarity and saved the weights of two identical nets in the siames model as **simlarity_model.h5** and **feature_generator_model.h5**.

How can I use these two saved weights to do predictions?

Similarity model =>

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
img_a_in = Input(shape = x_train.shape[1:], name = 'ImageA_Input')
img_b_in = Input(shape = x_train.shape[1:], name = 'ImageB_Input')
img_a_feat = feature_model(img_a_in)
img_b_feat = feature_model(img_b_in)
combined_features = concatenate([img_a_feat, img_b_feat], name = 'merge_features')
combined_features = Dense(16, activation = 'linear')(combined_features)
combined_features = BatchNormalization()(combined_features)
combined_features = Activation('relu')(combined_features)
combined_features = Dense(4, activation = 'linear')(combined_features)
combined_features = BatchNormalization()(combined_features)
combined_features = Activation('relu')(combined_features)
combined_features = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(combined_features)
similarity_model = Model(inputs = [img_a_in, img_b_in], outputs = [combined_features], name = 'Similarity_Model')
similarity_model.summary()
```

Feature generator model =>

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPool2D, Activation, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
img_in = Input(shape = x_train.shape[1:], name = 'FeatureNet_ImageInput')
n_layer = img_in
for i in range(2):
    n_layer = Conv2D(8*2**i, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'linear')(n_layer)
    n_layer = BatchNormalization()(n_layer)
    n_layer = Activation('relu')(n_layer)
    n_layer = Conv2D(16*2**i, kernel_size = (3,3), activation = 'linear')(n_layer)
    n_layer = BatchNormalization()(n_layer)
    n_layer = Activation('relu')(n_layer)
    n_layer = MaxPool2D((2,2))(n_layer)
n_layer = Flatten()(n_layer)
n_layer = Dense(32, activation = 'linear')(n_layer)
n_layer = Dropout(0.5)(n_layer)
n_layer = BatchNormalization()(n_layer)
n_layer = Activation('relu')(n_layer)
feature_model = Model(inputs = [img_in], outputs = [n_layer], name = 'FeatureGenerationModel')
feature_model.summary()
```

Saved weights =>

```
feature_model.save('feature_model.h5')
similarity.save('feature_model.h5')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save and load weights in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266383/save-and-load-weights-in-keras)

Comment: That answer explains how to save and load a model or weights, but i need to do predictions using saved and loaded model. Can someone provide any sample?