# How to load the latest checkpoint and save it as a model in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pickle

So, I was wondering how to load the latest checkpoint in Tensorflow having its path/directory and continue the training where I left off. And also how to load the latest checkpoint and save it as a complete model. Please help me

My code:

```
        cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath=checkpoint_path, 
            verbose=1, 
            save_weights_only=True,
            save_freq=1*batch_size)

        # Create a basic model instance
        model = create_model(training, output)
        model.save_weights(checkpoint_path.format(epoch=0))

        # Create a TensorBoard callback (for metrics monitoring)
        tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="chatbot/training/logs", histogram_freq=1, update_freq= 1, profile_batch= 1)

        # Train the model with the new callback
        model.fit(training, output, epochs=500, batch_size = batch_size, validation_data=(training, output), callbacks=[cp_callback, tb_callback], verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to your problem would be to save the entire model with the `ModelCheckpoint` callback.
You only have to remove the `save_weights_only` argument for it to work.

```
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath=checkpoint_path, 
            verbose=1,
            save_freq=1*batch_size)
```

To load the checkpoint and continue training at a later point in time, just call

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(checkpoint_path)
```

If you want to load a checkpoint given you only saved the model weights, you have to first build your model and transfer your saved weights into it.

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
```

If you need further information about loading and saving models, I would recommend reading the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize

This answer is referencing the answer of :
[Save and load weights in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266383/save-and-load-weights-in-keras)

Comment: so, it is like `model = create_model()` then `model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)` and the `model.fit()`?

Comment: As long as the model created by `create_model()` has the same architecture as the model from which you saved the weights, it should work

Comment: im saving a model using `model.save()`, so should just use `create_model()` and then load weights and save it? or how should i save the entire model, i dont undersatnd @nFininte

Comment: If you save your model with `model.save()`  it will save your architecture, weights, compilation information and optimizer state. The best/easiest thing for you would be to save the entire model instead of only saving the weights with the ModellCheckpoint callback and reload your saved model with `model = tf.keras.models.load_model()` whenever you want to continue training or use it for inference.